# Ember & Cypress | Integration test failing likely due to lack of store context

Tags: ember.js, integration-testing, cypress

I am working with Ember.js on the frontend and using Cypress.io for integration testing. I have a "Order Status" button that upon click is supposed to use data within the store to access the specific order and navigate to the Order Status page.

However within the test, upon click from the modal, the Order Status page cannot load and my test throws [this error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JQqoh.png):

> TypeError: Cannot read property ‘_internalModel’ of null

...in the console, which I think likely has to do with that route's model not finding the order from within the store and loading.

In the Cypress test, I've created the necessary routes to pass in session data, but am struggling to understand if the lack of store data is throwing this error, and how to fix it. It is important to note that this whole flow works 100% on its own - I'm just trying to get test coverage.

I'll attach snippets from the relevant files / functions below -- please do let me know if more information is needed. I really suspect that Cypress cannot access the Ember store, but after much research and experimenting, I'm not exactly sure what the issue is.

**order-status.js** - model function from route

```
async model({ order_id: orderId }) {
    let cachedOrder = this.get('store').peekRecord('order', orderId);
    return cachedOrder
      ? cachedOrder
      : await this.get('store').findRecord('order', orderId);
  },
```

**modal.hbs** - where we navigate from current page to order-status route

```
<fieldset>
  <span class="modal-text">See order status</span>
  <div class="inline-button-wrap">
    <button 
      {{action 'decline'}} 
      class="close-btn button-hollow-green">
        Close
    </button>
    <button 
      {{action 'accept'}} 
      class="order-status-btn">
       Order Status
     </button>
  </div>
</fieldset>
```

**test.js** - test that simulates clicking order status button above

```
it('order status btn navigates to order status page', () => {
  cy.server();
  cy.route('GET', '/api/session', sessionResponse);
  cy.route('GET', `/api/orders/*`, order);
  cy.visit('/');
  cy.get('.delivery-card .button-cta').click(); //opens modal 
  cy.get('#modal .order-status-btn').click(); //navigates to order-status
});
```

Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: ***In the Cypress test, I've created the necessary routes to pass in session data*** - if you are expecting `cy.route('GET', '/api/session', sessionResponse)` to supply data to the app (as the above line indicates) then you should use `cy.request()` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Whether stubbing API requests or not, Ember's store should behave as expected when used in conjunction with Cypress. The error mentioned is a good clue to the primary problem – an undefined model. It's not fully clear how your application is working while the Cypress test is failing and throwing an error, but a couple of changes (some in Ember, some in Cypress) should clear things up. Here's a breakdown for resolving this issue (some reverse engineering / assumptions made, from the code examples provided)...

Send along the order `id` via the button action that opens the modal (in the delivery-card HTML mark-up):

```
<button class="button-cta" {{action 'openModal' order.id}}>
  Open Order Status Modal
</button>
```

The `openModal` action passes along the order `id` as a param for the `model` on the subsequent mod**a**l route, when transitioning. In the **delivery-card.js** controller:

```
actions: {
  openModal(id) {
    this.transitionToRoute('modal', id); // <-- id
  }
}
```

Then, the modal's `accept` action passes along the `id` to the order status page as well, when transitioning. In the **modal.js** controller:

```
actions: {
  accept() {
    this.transitionToRoute('order-status', this.get('model.id')); // <-- here
  },

  decline() {
  ...
```

Further, in **order-status.js**, the argument passed to the model hook can be simplified as `params`:

```
async model(params) { // <-- just use params
  const id = params.id; // <-- id
  const cachedOrder = this.get('store').peekRecord('order', id); // <-- id

  return cachedOrder
    ? cachedOrder
    : await this.get('store').findRecord('order', id); // <-- id
}
```

Finally, some changes to **test.js**:

```
it('order status btn navigates to order status page', () => {

  cy.server();
  cy.route('GET', `/api/session`, 'fixture:session.json'); // <-- here
  cy.route('GET', `/api/orders`, 'fixture:orders.json');   // <-- here
  cy.visit('/');
  cy.get('.delivery-card .button-cta').click(); // opens modal
  cy.get('#modal .order-status-btn').click(); // navigates to order-status

  // here, verify that an order status is displayed
  cy.get('.current-status')
    .should(($el) => {
      const statusTextValue = $el[0].innerText;
      expect(statusTextValue).to.not.be.empty;
    });

});
```

The API `GET` requests are [stubbed](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Stubbing) with [fixtures](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/network-requests.html#Fixtures) using standard Cypress conventions.

Finally, here's a screenshot of the Cypress runner, showing only the initial `XHR STUB` request when GET-ting `orders`. Notice that Ember's store methods, `peekRecord` and `findRecord`, used in the order-status.js route file, do not generate any further XHR requests, and, result in no errors being thrown. Ember's store is functioning as anticipated.

[image]